# Spring-data and Hibernate's auto-generated IDs

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm using Spring-data's `PagingAndSortingRepository` on my entities (having `@GeneratedValue` IDs). Is there any way so that PUT and POST with the IDs set in the payload either won't work and throw an exception or just ignore the provided ID and use Hibernate's (via some configuration, etc., I know I can programatically check for it (cumbersome, meh))?

The ability to provide IDs which will be used and persisted screws up the whole database.

Thanks!

Comment: my previous statement of trying another @GeneratedValue strategy, does not seem to work. You could make your entity model, not show the ID attribute (make it private)

Comment: Or you can just remove the Id attribute from the payload

Comment: Show some code of what you have and a bit proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You do  not say if you are using Spring MVC but assuming you are then you can use a custom  data binder to prevent binding of certain fields.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder

You can apply this on a global level via a Controller Advice:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

> Classes annotated with @ControllerAdvice can contain
>   @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute annotated methods,
>   and these methods will apply to @RequestMapping methods across all
>   controller hierarchies as opposed to the controller hierarchy within
>   which they are declared.

e.g.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class BaseControllerAdvice {

    @InitBinder()
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] { "id", "version" });
    }
}
```